# css animated spinning divs have also spun text 180 degrees

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have created spinning divs on my website within a grid layout timetable. The square div spins 180 degrees and the initial image that displays changes to text as the div spins. My problem at the moment is as I am using css3 for the animation when the text shows the text is also spun 180 degrees so it is reversed.

The code is below.

[Here is a livelink](http://www.cambridgedesigncompany.com/newpage.html) of the spinning divs, they are the divs that show stage1,2,3 etc. I shall remove this link once the question has been answered for the posterity of the post in the future.

***CSS FOR SPINNING DIVS***

```
.hover-img, .hover-img.hover_effect {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #CCCCB2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
    width: 400px;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img4 {
    background-color: #f47878;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img5 {
    background-color: #f6c447;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img6 {
    background-color: #92cf96;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img7 {
    background-color: #f47878;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img12 {
    background-color: #92cf96;
}
.trigger:hover .hover-img img {
    display: none;
}
```

***HTML FOR SPINNING DIVS***

```
<div class="col">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP1.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 4</div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5"><img src="STEP3.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 5</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6"><img src="STEP2.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 6</div>
        </div>
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img7"><img src="STEP4.jpg" width="200"/>Text Here 7</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This great tutorial will probably help you with your issue (and the effect is even better) I would recomend you to try it: http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip   Demo: http://davidwalsh.name/demo/css-flip.php

Comment: you could apply a <p> tag for text you want to correct and then apply a `transform:scaleX(-1)` to flip

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, it's working for me:

```css
.hover-img, .hover-img.hover_effect {
position: relative;
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
text-align: center;
font-size: 0;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #CCCCB2;
border-radius: 5px;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
width: 400px;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
-webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
-o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
transform: rotateY(180deg);
font-size: 14px;
color: #FFF;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img4 {
background-color: #f47878;
}


.trigger:hover .hover-img img {
display: none;
}

.trigger > .hover-img.img4 > span
{
  display:none;
}

.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img4 > span
{
    display:block;
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
        <div class="trigger">
            <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4"><img src="STEP1.jpg" width="200"/>
                <span>Text Here 4</span>
            </div>
        </div>
  
</div>
```

I am just add one span with some styles on above code check and if you have any doubt let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Here is your Html:

```
 <div class="col">
    <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img4">
            <img src="STEP1.jpg" width="200" />
            <p>Text Here 4</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img5">
            <img src="STEP3.jpg" width="200" />
            <p>Text Here 5</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col">
    <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img6">
            <img src="STEP2.jpg" width="200" />
            <p>Text Here 6</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trigger">
        <div tabindex="0" class="maincontent hover-img img7">
            <img src="STEP4.jpg" width="200" />
            <p>Text Here 7</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

check this css:

```
    .hover-img, .hover-img.hover_effect {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #CCCCB2;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.trigger.large .hover-img, .trigger.large .hover-img.hover_effect {
    width: 400px;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFF;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img4 {
    background-color: #f47878;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img5 {
    background-color: #f6c447;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img6 {
    background-color: #92cf96;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img7 {
    background-color: #f47878;
}
.trigger:hover > .hover-img.img12 {
    background-color: #92cf96;
}
.trigger:hover .hover-img img {
    display: none;
}
.trigger:hover p {
    display:block;
    transform:scaleX(-1)
}
}
```

Here is working [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/carunchandran/2j9895rv/)

I have wrapped your text to a `<p>` tag. And added the following styles.

```
.trigger:hover p {
display:block;
transform:scaleX(-1)
}
```

Refer transform [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)